# Substring comparision with one mismatch

Tags: c++, string, similarity

The following is code for comparing a String A and String B with atmost one mismatch 
i.e., 
ABC is same as ABX or AXC or XBC but, not same as AXZ

I did check several cases but, the website says it provides wrong answer. Could someone help to figure out where does this code fail?
Also, I'd be glad if someone could provide a better algorithm for the same problem.

TY

```
int compare(string a,  int pos, string b)   {
int count = 0;
int length = b.length()-1;
int mid = b.length() /2;

if(pos+length >= a.length())
    return 0;

for(int i=0,j=pos;i<=mid;i++,j++)   {       
    if(i == mid)    {
        if(a[j] != b[i])
            count ++;
    }
    else    {
        if(a[j] != b[i])
            count ++;
        if(a[pos+length - i] != b[length -i]) 
            count ++;
    }
    if(count >= 2) return 0;
}
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Not a homework but, from a programming website

Comment: What's wrong about discussing homework here anyway?

Comment: @jogojapan: Nothing. It just should be tagged as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that if `b.length()` is even, then you compare `a[pos + b.length() / 2]` to `b[b.length() / 2]` *twice*: once when `i == mid - 1`, and once when `i == mid`. So something like `compare("abcd", 0, "abbd")` returns `0`, because it counts the `'c'`-vs.-`'b'` discrepancy as two separate mismatches.

I recommend that you simply strip out all logic related to `mid`. It serves no purpose other than massively complicating your code. If you iterate straight from `0` to `b.length() - 1`, you'll be much better off.

Comment: Not only that, but the current access pattern, working from both ends of two buffers at once, has horrid cache behavior.

Comment: @BenVoigt: True, but I really think that's the least problem here. If there were a good reason for the double-ended approach, then the cache behavior might or might not be enough to overrule that reason; but since there doesn't seem to be any reason at all, I think it's moot.

Comment: Thanks Ruakh ... I got that solved
I had to put up the mid logic hoping it would allow my code to run faster for larger inputs
But, it seems that I need to look for a new algorithm rather than optimizing this Naive method which uses (N*N) time
Could you suggest a better approach for this operation which uses lesser time.
TY

Comment: @Rama: Your `compare` function takes O(*n*) time, where *n* is the length of `b`. It's impossible to decrease its algorithmic complexity any further, since you have to examine all of `b`. If by "this Naive method" you don't mean the `compare` function itself, but rather the whole approach of which `compare` is just one part, then you haven't given me anywhere near enough information: I don't even know what you're trying to accomplish!

Comment: @Ruakh .. I Take two strings A and B.
Where, I need positions wherever I find B-string is a substring of A with atmost one mismatch
Example::
A: abcdefghabX
B: abc
Output: 1 9
The positions of substring matches of abc in "A"

Comment: @Rama: There are various things you can do to tweak your algorithm, but as a first step, I'd suggest just changing your function declaration from `int compare(string a,  int pos, string b)` (pass-by-value) to `int compare(const string & a,  int pos, const string & b)` (pass-by-reference). That way the two strings don't have to be fully copied, in their entirety, every single time you call `compare`.